# What is the purpose of setTitle(String title) method in ConstraintLayout 1.1.0?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

As of 1.1.0-beta1, ConstraintLayout source code includes field `mTitle`, setter and getter for it, also it can be set up via xml attribute. It's not used anywhere inside library (at least search find no occurrences).

What is the purpose of this field?

Comment: I don't know, but 'setTitle' and 'getTitle' are no longer accessible in the "1.1.0" official release